# replace inline assembly tailcall function epilogue with Intrinsics for x86/x64 msvc

Tags: c++, x86, inline-assembly

I took an inactive project and already fixed a lot in it, but I don't get an Intrinsics replacement correctly to work for the used inline assembly, which is no longer supported in the x86/x64 msvc compilers.

```
#define XCALL(uAddr)  \
__asm { mov esp, ebp }   \
__asm { pop ebp }        \
__asm { mov eax, uAddr } \
__asm { jmp eax }
```

Use cases:

```
static oCMOB * CreateNewInstance() {
    XCALL(0x00718590);
}

int Copy(class zSTRING const &, enum zTSTR_KIND const &) {
    XCALL(0x0046C2D0);
}

void TrimLeft(char) {
    XCALL(0x0046C630);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet goes at the bottom of a function (which can't inline, and must be compiled with `ebp` as a frame pointer, and no other registers that need restoring).  It looks quite brittle, or else it's only useful in cases where you didn't need inline asm at all.

Instead of returning, it jumps to `uAddr`, which is equivalent to making a tailcall.

There aren't intrinsics for arbitrary jumps or manipulation of the stack.  If you need that, you're out of luck.  It doesn't make sense to ask about this snippet by itself, only with enough context to see how it's being used.  i.e. is it important which return address is on the stack, or is it ok for it to compile to call/ret instead of `jmp` to that address?  (See the first version of this answer for a simple example of using it as a function pointer.)

---

**From your update, your use-cases are just a very clunky way to make wrappers for absolute function pointers.**

We can instead **define `static const` function pointers** of the right types, so no wrapper is needed and the compiler can call directly from wherever you use these.  `static const` is how we let the compile know it can fully inline the function pointers, and doesn't need to store them anywhere as data if it doesn't want to, just like normal `static const int xyz = 2;`

```
struct oCMOB;
class zSTRING;
enum zTSTR_KIND { a, b, c };  // enum forward declarations are illegal

// C syntax
//static oCMOB* (*const CreateNewInstance)() = (oCMOB *(*const)())0x00718590;

// C++11
static const auto CreateNewInstance = reinterpret_cast<oCMOB *(*)()>(0x00718590);
// passing an enum by const-reference is dumb.  By value is more efficient for integer types
static const auto Copy = reinterpret_cast<int (*)(class zSTRING const &, enum zTSTR_KIND const &)>(0x0046C2D0);
static const auto TrimLeft = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(char)> (0x0046C630);

void foo() {
    oCMOB *inst = CreateNewInstance();
    (void)inst; // silence unused warning

    zSTRING *dummy = nullptr;  // work around instantiating an incomplete type
    int result = Copy(*dummy, c);
    (void) result;

    TrimLeft('a');
}
```

It also compiles just fine with x86-64 and 32-bit x86 MSVC, and gcc/clang 32 and 64-bit [**on the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'/*%0Astatic+oCMOB+*+CreateNewInstance()+%7B%0A++++XCALL(0x00718590)%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+Copy(class+zSTRING+const+%26,+enum+zTSTR_KIND+const+%26)+%7B%0A++++XCALL(0x0046C2D0)%3B%0A%7D%0A*/%0A%0Astruct+oCMOB%3B%0Aclass+zSTRING%3B%0Aenum+zTSTR_KIND+%7B+a,+b,+c+%7D%3B++//+enum+forward+declarations+are+illegal%0A%0A//+C+syntax,+also+works+in+C%2B%2B.++For+C+only+we+could+cast+to+void*%0A//static+oCMOB*+(*const+CreateNewInstance)(void)+%3D+(oCMOB+*(*const)(void))0x00718590%3B%0A%0A//+C%2B%2B11%0Astatic+const+auto+CreateNewInstance+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3CoCMOB+*(*)()%3E(0x00718590)%3B%0A//+passing+an+enum+by+const-reference+is+dumb.++By+value+is+more+efficient+for+integer+types%0Astatic+const+auto+Copy+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cint+(*)(class+zSTRING+const+%26,+enum+zTSTR_KIND+const+%26)%3E(0x0046C2D0)%3B%0Astatic+const+auto+TrimLeft+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cvoid+(*)(char)%3E+(0x0046C630)%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++oCMOB+*inst+%3D+CreateNewInstance()%3B%0A++++(void)inst%3B+//+silence+unused+warning%0A%0A++++zSTRING+*dummy+%3D+nullptr%3B++//+work+around+instantiating+an+incomplete+type%0A++++int+result+%3D+Copy(*dummy,+c)%3B%0A++++(void)+result%3B%0A%0A++++TrimLeft(!'a!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A//+GNU+C+hacks+to+get+call+rel32+in+position-dependent+code%0A//+clang+does+this+on+its+own+with+-m32,+but+not+64-bit+non-PIE.%0A//+It+isn!'t+safe+in+64-bit+PIE+code.%0A//+-fPIE+code+can+be+linked+into+a+non-PIE+executable,+but+it!'s+sub-optimal%0A//+maybe+it!'s+best+to+just+error+at+compile+time+with+-fPIE,+esp.+if+we+can!'t+do+it+*safely*+(gcc)%0A%0A%23ifdef+__GNUC__%0A//+This+foo+asm(%22name%22)+is+for+setting+the+asm+symbol+name.%0A//+It!'s+supposed+to+be+a+symbol,+not+numeric.%0A//+this+only+works+as+long+as+gcc+doesn!'t+append+@PLT+or+@GOTPCREL+to+the+symbol+name%0A//oCMOB+*+CreateNewInstance(void)+asm(%220x00718590%22)%3B++++//+broken+with+-fPIE:+we+get+0x00718590@GOTPCREL%0A%0Aextern+%22C%22+%7B%0A++++//+hidden+visibility+means+that+even+with+-fPIE,%0A++++//+calls+will+go+*directly*+to+that+address,+not+via+the+PLT+or+GOT.%0A++++oCMOB+*+CNI(void)+__attribute__((__visibility__(%22hidden%22)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+To+avoid+extern+%22C%22,+use+the+mangled+name.%0A//+There+might+be+a+way+with+Extended+asm+to+get+GCC+to+print+the+mangled+name%0A//asm(%22CNI+%3D+0x718590%22)%3B++//+set+the+address+of+a+symbol,+like+%60org+0x71...+/+CNI:%60%0Aasm(%22.set+CNI,+0x718590%22)%3B++//+alternate+syntax+for+the+same+thing%0A%0A//+Separately+creating+an+object+file+with+a+symbol+definition+for+CNI+might+also+work%0A//+just+comment+out+the+asm()+statement+and+let+the+compiler+emit+asm+that+uses+the+name.%0A%0Avoid+*test()+%7B%0A++++CNI()%3B++++//+expected+address+called%0A%0A++++return+(void*)CNI%3B++//+gcc+-fPIE:+RIP%2B0x718590+instead+of+the+right+relative+displacement+:(%0A++++//+clang+appears+to+work%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:46.61016949152542,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ox',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:60.56056056056056,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:39.43943943943944,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),k:53.38983050847458,l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  (And also non-x86 architectures).  This is the 32-bit asm output from MSVC, so you could compare with what you get for your nasty wrapper functions.  You can see that it's basically inlined the useful part (`mov eax, uAddr` / `jmp` or `call`) into the caller.

```
;; x86 MSVC -O3
$T1 = -4                                                ; size = 4
?foo@@YAXXZ PROC                                        ; foo
        push    ecx
        mov     eax, 7439760                          ; 00718590H
        call    eax

        lea     eax, DWORD PTR $T1[esp+4]
        mov     DWORD PTR $T1[esp+4], 2       ; the by-reference enum
        push    eax
        push    0                             ; the dummy nullptr
        mov     eax, 4637392                          ; 0046c2d0H
        call    eax

        push    97                                  ; 00000061H
        mov     eax, 4638256                          ; 0046c630H
        call    eax

        add     esp, 16                             ; 00000010H
        ret     0
?foo@@YAXXZ ENDP
```

For repeated calls to the same function, the compiler would keep the function pointer in a call-preserved register.

---

For some reason even with 32-bit position-*dependent* code, we don't get a direct `call rel32`.  The linker can calculate the relative offset from the call-site to the absolute target at link time, so there's no reason for the compiler to use a register-indirect `call`.

If we didn't tell the compiler to create position-independent code, it's a useful optimization in this case to address absolute addresses relative to the code, for jumps/calls.

In 32-bit code, every possible destination address is in range from every possible source address, but in 64-bit it's harder.  **In 32-bit mode, clang does spot this optimization**!  But even in 32-bit mode, MSVC and gcc miss it.

I played around with some stuff with gcc/clang:

```
// don't use
oCMOB * CreateNewInstance(void) asm("0x00718590");
```

Kind of works, but only as a total hack.  Gcc just uses that string as if it were a symbol, so it feeds `call 0x00718590` to the assembler, which handles it correctly (generating an absolute relocation which links just fine in a non-PIE executable).  But with `-fPIE`, we it emits `0x00718590@GOTPCREL` as a symbol name, so we're screwed.

Of course, in 64-bit mode a PIE executable or library will be out of range of that absolute address so only non-PIE makes sense anyway.

---

Another idea was to define the symbol in asm with an absolute address, and provide a prototype that would get gcc to only use it directly, without @PLT or going through the GOT.  (I maybe could have done that for the `func() asm("0x...");` hack, too, using hidden visibility.)

I only realized after hacking this up with the "hidden" attribute that this is useless in position-independent code, so you can't use this in a shared library or PIE executable anyway.

`extern "C"` is not necessary, but means I didn't have to mess with name mangling in the inline asm.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__

extern "C" {
    // hidden visibility means that even in a PIE executable, or shared lib,
    // calls will go *directly* to that address, not via the PLT or GOT.
    oCMOB * CNI(void) __attribute__((__visibility__("hidden")));
}
//asm("CNI = 0x718590");  // set the address of a symbol, like `org 0x71... / CNI:`
asm(".set CNI, 0x718590");  // alternate syntax for the same thing


void *test() {
    CNI();    // works

    return (void*)CNI;  // gcc: RIP+0x718590 instead of the relative displacement needed to reach it?
    // clang appears to work
}
#endif
```

disassembly of compiled+linked gcc output for `test`, **from [Godbolt, using the binary output to see how it assembled+linked](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'/*%0Astatic+oCMOB+*+CreateNewInstance()+%7B%0A++++XCALL(0x00718590)%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+Copy(class+zSTRING+const+%26,+enum+zTSTR_KIND+const+%26)+%7B%0A++++XCALL(0x0046C2D0)%3B%0A%7D%0A*/%0A%0Astruct+oCMOB%3B%0Aclass+zSTRING%3B%0Aenum+zTSTR_KIND+%7B+a,+b,+c+%7D%3B++//+enum+forward+declarations+are+illegal%0A%0A//+C+syntax,+also+works+in+C%2B%2B.++For+C+only+we+could+cast+to+void*%0A//static+oCMOB*+(*const+CreateNewInstance)(void)+%3D+(oCMOB+*(*const)(void))0x00718590%3B%0A%0A//+C%2B%2B11%0Astatic+const+auto+CreateNewInstance+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3CoCMOB+*(*)()%3E(0x00718590)%3B%0A//+passing+an+enum+by+const-reference+is+dumb.++By+value+is+more+efficient+for+integer+types%0Astatic+const+auto+Copy+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cint+(*)(class+zSTRING+const+%26,+enum+zTSTR_KIND+const+%26)%3E(0x0046C2D0)%3B%0Astatic+const+auto+TrimLeft+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cvoid+(*)(char)%3E+(0x0046C630)%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++oCMOB+*inst+%3D+CreateNewInstance()%3B%0A++++(void)inst%3B+//+silence+unused+warning%0A%0A++++zSTRING+*dummy+%3D+nullptr%3B++//+work+around+instantiating+an+incomplete+type%0A++++int+result+%3D+Copy(*dummy,+c)%3B%0A++++(void)+result%3B%0A%0A++++TrimLeft(!'a!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A//+GNU+C+hacks+to+get+call+rel32+in+position-dependent+code%0A//+clang+does+this+on+its+own+with+-m32,+but+not+64-bit+non-PIE.%0A//+It+isn!'t+safe+in+64-bit+PIE+code.%0A//+-fPIE+code+can+be+linked+into+a+non-PIE+executable,+but+it!'s+sub-optimal%0A//+maybe+it!'s+best+to+just+error+at+compile+time+with+-fPIE,+esp.+if+we+can!'t+do+it+*safely*+(gcc)%0A%0A%23ifdef+__GNUC__%0A//+This+foo+asm(%22name%22)+is+for+setting+the+asm+symbol+name.%0A//+It!'s+supposed+to+be+a+symbol,+not+numeric.%0A//+this+only+works+as+long+as+gcc+doesn!'t+append+@PLT+or+@GOTPCREL+to+the+symbol+name%0A//oCMOB+*+CreateNewInstance(void)+asm(%220x00718590%22)%3B++++//+broken+with+-fPIE:+we+get+0x00718590@GOTPCREL%0A%0Aextern+%22C%22+%7B%0A++++//+hidden+visibility+means+that+even+with+-fPIE,%0A++++//+calls+will+go+*directly*+to+that+address,+not+via+the+PLT+or+GOT.%0A++++oCMOB+*+CNI(void)+__attribute__((__visibility__(%22hidden%22)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+To+avoid+extern+%22C%22,+use+the+mangled+name.%0A//+There+might+be+a+way+with+Extended+asm+to+get+GCC+to+print+the+mangled+name%0A//asm(%22CNI+%3D+0x718590%22)%3B++//+set+the+address+of+a+symbol,+like+%60org+0x71...+/+CNI:%60%0Aasm(%22.set+CNI,+0x718590%22)%3B++//+alternate+syntax+for+the+same+thing%0A%0A//+Separately+creating+an+object+file+with+a+symbol+definition+for+CNI+might+also+work%0A//+just+comment+out+the+asm()+statement+and+let+the+compiler+emit+asm+that+uses+the+name.%0A%0Avoid+*test()+%7B%0A++++CNI()%3B++++//+expected+address+called%0A%0A++++return+(void*)CNI%3B++//+gcc+-fPIE:+RIP%2B0x718590+instead+of+the+right+relative+displacement+:(%0A++++//+clang+appears+to+work%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:42.06291990628659,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:28.005606966201,l:'4',m:64.9235694294521,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:29.93147312751242,l:'4',m:79.67967967967968,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:20.320320320320317,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:29.93147312751242,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**:

```
 # gcc -O3  (non-PIE).  Clang makes pretty much the same code, with a direct call and mov imm.
 sub    rsp,0x8
 call   718590 <CNI>
 mov    eax,0x718590
 add    rsp,0x8
 ret
```

With `-fPIE`, gcc+gas emits `lea    rax,[rip+0x718590]        # b18ab0 <CNI+0x400520>`, i.e. it uses the absolute address as an offset from RIP, instead of subtracting.  I guess that's because gcc literally emits `lea    CNI(%rip),%rax`, and we've defined CNI as an assemble-time symbol with that numeric value.  Oops.  So it's not quite like a label with that address like you'd get with `.org 0x718590;  CNI:`.

But since we can only use rel32 `call` in non-PIE executables, this is ok unless you compile with `-no-pie` but forget `-fno-pie`, in which case you're screwed. :/

Providing a separate object file with the symbol definition might have worked.

Clang appears to do exactly what we want, though, even with -fPIE, with its built-in assembler.  This machine code could only have linked with `-fno-pie` (the default on Godbolt, not the default on many distros.)

```
 # disassembly of clang -fPIE machine-code output for test()
 push   rax
 call   718590 <CNI>
 lea    rax,[rip+0x3180b3]        # 718590 <CNI>
 pop    rcx
 ret
```

So this is actually safe (but sub-optimal because `lea rel32` is worse than `mov imm32`.)  With `-m32 -fPIE`, it doesn't even assemble.

Comment: What code would be generated if using debug build instead of release build?

Comment: @rcgldr: click on the Godbolt link and change the command line options if you're curious.  That's why I include Godbolt links in my answers!  It would probably use `call/ret`, though.  So good point that this changes the stack layout that the jump target sees depending on optimization level.

Comment: @PeterCordes I like your answer, but I don't know if it would work properly, I added some use cases to my question for clarification, especially because it needs several attributes and return types.

Comment: @Xervia: you should be able to just define `static const` function pointers with those numeric values.  Making trampoline functions with inline asm just looks totally stupid and pointless.

Comment: @Xervia: updated with `static const` function pointers, and an attempt to get gcc/clang to emit more efficient direct `call rel32` instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks, you helped me a lot, but since my use case is mainly in class-based functions and I used the old C standard based on the first variant of your answer, I still have problems with constructors and other operators, see: [/q/52019317](/q/52019317)

Comment: are i correct understand that all this c++ declarations - only interface for call api from external dll ? like we have declaration of system api in header files. the OP really not need any code/implementation of this function/classes . it only need link it (redirect call) to some external dll, but by some reason dont have lib file for this dll which usually used for static link to dll

Comment: if yes, exist enough simply and elegant solution without any code. i be ask - are need that all this functions will be *imported* like usual windows api import ?

Comment: @RbMm: ask the OP, I just answered the question as written.  It was only after they pinged me about a followup question that I found out these absolute addresses are just in a DLL.

Comment: @Xervia: In the old C version of my answer, the function pointer was a *local* variable inside another function.  So it didn't need to be `static const` to optimize away nicely.  If you put it at global scope, make it `static const`.  And see RbMn's comments here and on your followup.