# Best way to declare member functions in a hpp file that point to an existing memory address

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, x86

Due to changes in the MVSC x86/x64 compiler, I cannot use `__asm(jmp addr)` to perform direct functions via the memory address in the project.

For non-member functions, this Q&A did the trick: [replace inline assembly tailcall function epilogue with Intrinsics for x86/x64 msvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010509/replace-inline-assembly-tailcall-function-epilogue-with-intrinsics-for-x86-x64-m)

But for member functions, I now need an alternative; it must be pointed out that this is also required for constructors and deconstructors, as well as for functions of the same name for which my variant does not work. Of course, suggestions for improvement are also welcome, and yes, I only have the memory address, so there is no other way to call it up.

zstring.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "../asmjmp.h"

int __cdecl operator==(class zSTRING const &, char const * const);
int __cdecl operator==(class zSTRING const &, class zSTRING const &);

class zSTRING
{
public:
    zSTRING() {
        __asm( jmp 0x00402AF0);
    }

    zSTRING(zSTRING const &) {
        __asm( jmp 0x00416500);
    }

    ~zSTRING() {
         __asm( jmp 0x00401160);
    }

   int Overwrite(unsigned int, class zSTRING const &) {
        __asm( jmp 0x0046B6A0);
    }

    int Overwrite(string) {
        __asm( jmp 0x0046B6FF);
    }

    int Insert(unsigned int, class zSTRING const &) {
        __asm( jmp 0x0046B400);
    }

    /* My Variant: */
    int (*Insert)(unsigned int, class zSTRING const &) = ((int(*)(unsigned int, class zSTRING const &))0x0046B400);

    int Delete(class zSTRING const &, enum zTSTR_KIND) {
        __asm( jmp 0x0046BCF0);
    }

    /* My Variant: */
    int (*Delete)(class zSTRING const &, enum zTSTR_KIND) = ((int(*)(class zSTRING const &, enum zTSTR_KIND))0x0046BCF0);

    char * ToChar() const
    {
        __asm( jmp 0x004639D0);
    }

    zSTRING Copied(unsigned int, unsigned long) const
    {
        __asm( jmp 0x0046C170);
    }

    zSTRING &operator+=(char const *) {
        __asm( jmp 0x0067A7B0);
    }

    /* My Variant (without knowing if it would work): */
    zSTRING (*&operator+=)(char const *) = ((zSTRING (*)(char const *))0x0067A7B0);

    char & operator[](unsigned int) {
        __asm( jmp 0x00445A20);
    }

    /* My Variant (without knowing if it would work): */
    char & (operator[])(unsigned int) = ((char &(*)(unsigned int))0x00445A20);
};
```

Comment: What compiler is this? `__asm` isn't standard C++, so any answer you get will be specific to that compiler.

Comment: Need context.  Why do you need `jmp` instructions?  My understanding is that the resolution of function addresses is the *linker's* responsibility.

Comment: Casting the number to a function pointer and then calling it could work. But you can't declare `operator??` as a pointer. Instead, make a normal member function, and inside perform the pointer cast and call the result. You might need to specify a calling convention as well.

Comment: I am using the latest mvsc compiler. The code uses `jmp` statement to execute functions of an already compiled program loaded by `*.dll` files, the classes are needed as an interface between my modification and the original program.

Comment: You can create a LIB file from an existing DLL.

Comment: So you also have an x86-64 version of this library, but you still don't have proper symbols for either that would allow you to link it?  You know you can't call code in a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit process, right?  This whole thing sounds like the wrong solution to the problem, vs. giving your linker the right symbols to link normally when you just provide prototypes.  This hard-coded absolute-address stuff only makes sense for some kind of code-injection or custom JIT into static buffers, not for normal linking to a DLL.

Comment: absolute unclear for what you need jmp

Comment: @RbMm: It makes these functions into tailcall wrappers, presumably with `__thiscall`, assuming they didn't create a stack frame or else it would break things.  Looks pretty bogus to me, especially using different syntax from the OP's previous question [replace inline assembly tailcall function epilogue with Intrinsics for x86/x64 msvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52010509) where it was valid MSVC `__asm { pop ebp; blah blah; jmp eax; }`.  I don't think this will compile.

Comment: @PeterCordes - we of course can declare functions in c++ and implement function in asm file for use all power of asm. this is easy and for member functions too. with special macros we can get mangled name of any function and then use this name in asm. i not once do this. say for current class and *cl* will be `??0zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ`,
`??0zSTRING@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z`,
`??1zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ`,
`?Overwrite@zSTRING@@QEAAHIAEBV1@@Z`, 
`?Insert@zSTRING@@QEAAHIAEBV1@@Z` etc but for what need hardcoded(!!) jmps - until not understand.

Comment: if function implementation need do something that can not be implemented in c/c++ - need declare it in c++ and implement in asm. say we can use next macros : `#define __ASM_FUNCTION __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__" proc\r\n" __FUNCDNAME__ " endp"))
#define _ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;}
#define ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;return 0;}
#define CPP_FUNCTION __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))`

Comment: and every functions (which declared c++ and implemeted in asm) add `zSTRING(zSTRING const &)_ASM_FUNCTION;` - `_ASM_FUNCTION` (if void return) or `ASM_FUNCTION` suffix. for get preprocessor output. in release build `#define ASM_FUNCTION`

Comment: @RbMm: I didn't say the OP's code was a *good* idea, but that's what they're using `jmp` for.  Creating an object file with the right symbols so this can link properly/normally would be much better.  You might want to post an answer about how to do that for Windows, and also leave a comment on the linked question.  I mentioned that idea in my answer there, but IDK the details.

Comment: are addresses to which you try jmp - **exported** from your dll ? if yes, you need simply create lib file for this dll. this is simply, even if you have no src code for dll - create new project with output name equal to this dll. and create your own empty implementation for every function which you want call. simply return 0 from function or empty body for `void` functions. for build lib not need implementation. need only correct names. and that use this lib.with you declaration of functions - to every function / class add `__declspec(dllimport)`

Comment: if this addresses not exported - how you plan got it ? absolute hard-coded in compile time ? but even in this case - 1. declare all with `__declspec(dllimport)`. build. you got many errors with - unresolved symbol `__imp_*` - copy this names add asm file to project. in this file for every name declare in `CONST` or `BSS` (if you resolve address in runtime) section - `__imp_?Insert@zSTRING@@QEAAHIAEBV1@@Z DQ *h`.. `__imp_?TrimLeft@@YAXD@Z DQ *h` and so on. and you got what you need

Comment: and also separate declare all symbols as `public` in asm, say `public __imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want that some function containing single `jmp` instruction to some address - you need declare it with `__declspec(dllimport)` (this is Microsoft Specific and work only for *CL* compiler but think another compilers have equvalent syntax). say for example

```
void __declspec(dllimport) TrimLeft(char);
```

in case you ned this for all member functions in class - declare all class with this:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) zSTRING
{
    zSTRING();
    // .. more declarations
};
```

this will have effect on all not virtual member functions and static data member for class like it declared with `__declspec(dllimport)`

when function declared with `__declspec(dllimport)` compiler declared extern pointer variable:

```
extern void* __imp___FUNCDNAME__;
```

where [`__FUNCDNAME__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) is decorated name of function + `__imp_` prefix; and every time when you call such function compiler generate `call __imp___FUNCDNAME__` instruction (after pass function arguments to registers or stack). with [Edit and Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2017) options compiler usually generate less optimized code:

```
call func
func:
jmp __imp___FUNCDNAME__ ; exactly what you try - single jmp in function body
```

which is by fact equivalent to single `call __imp___FUNCDNAME__`

now obvious that for every imported functions `void* __imp___FUNCDNAME__` must be somewhere defined and containing real function address. otherwise you got well known linker error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

usually we use *LIB* file where exactly defined `__imp___FUNCDNAME__` symbols - in this case linker put all this `__imp_*` variable in `IAT` section of PE and describe it in import section. as result loader assign correct address for every `__imp___FUNCDNAME__` when load your image.

if you try import this functions from some DLL and this DLL **export** this functions - you must have *LIB* file for this. even if you have no *LIB* - you can easy create you yourself - create separate project with output file name exactly match to dll name from which you will call code and "implement" all this functions with `__declspec(dllexport)` for every single function or class. implementation of every function -  can be empty or single `return 0;` - really when we build lib - it not containing any code (as result implementation can be fake/empty). it containing exactly function names and dll name (because this output file name for project must be exactly dll name. but say project target - exe or dll - does not matter). in general - this must look like:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) TrimLeft(char)
{
}

class __declspec(dllexport) zSTRING
{
public:
    zSTRING()
    {

    }

    int Overwrite(unsigned int, class zSTRING const &)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //...
};
```

you easy build this code and got *LIB* file (import library) all what you need.

in case this functions not exported - unclear from where you got addresses, but in any case - this can not be **hard-coded absolute** addresses. you can in extreme case use hard-coded *RVA* from *DLL*... in any case if this functions **not exported** - you need yourself define all `__imp___FUNCDNAME__` yourself. and yourself assign correct function addresses for it at begin.

because `__FUNCDNAME__` usually containing illegal for `C/C++` symbols - you will be need declare it in asm, something like:

```
_BSS segment

__imp_?TrimLeft@@YAXD@Z DQ ?
__imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ DQ ?
__imp_??1zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ DQ ?
__imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z DQ ?
__imp_?Insert@zSTRING@@QEAAHIAEBV1@@Z DQ ?

public __imp_?TrimLeft@@YAXD@Z
public __imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ
public __imp_??1zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ
public __imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z
public __imp_?Insert@zSTRING@@QEAAHIAEBV1@@Z

_BSS ends
```

and implement function for resolve import yourself

```
resolveimport proc

    lea rax,[rcx + rva_1]
    mov __imp_?TrimLeft@@YAXD@Z,rax

    lea rax,[rcx + rva_2]
    mov __imp_??0zSTRING@@QEAA@XZ,rax

    ;...

    ret

resolveimport endp
```

say you call `resolveimport` from *c++* code with address of dll - `resolveimport(LoadLibraryW(L"my.dll"));`